# OpenCV Java JNIEXPORT memory management

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have a question abour memory management of java port of OpenCV.

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III
          (JNIEnv* env, jclass, jint rows, jint cols, jint type)
        {
            try {
                LOGD("Mat::n_1Mat__III()");

                Mat* _retval_ = new Mat( rows, cols, type );

                return (jlong) _retval_;
            } catch(cv::Exception e) {
                LOGD("Mat::n_1Mat__III() catched cv::Exception: %s", e.what());
                jclass je = env->FindClass("org/opencv/core/CvException");
                if(!je) je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
                env->ThrowNew(je, e.what());
                return 0;
            } catch (...) {
                LOGD("Mat::n_1Mat__III() catched unknown exception (...)");
                jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
                env->ThrowNew(je, "Unknown exception in JNI code {Mat::n_1Mat__III()}");
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

This code block is taken from '..\OpenCV-2.4.5\modules\java\generator\src\cpp\Mat.cpp'. My question is about following part:

```
Mat* _retval_ = new Mat( rows, cols, type );
return (jlong) _retval_;
```

It returns mat objects address by casting it to `jlong` and does not delete the object. So, **how does the memory management is done**? Does java runs Garbage Collector? Or are there any other code in C++ side that clears the memory somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no memory manage done here.

The function really returns a pointer to a heap-allocated object without caring about the memory management.

Actually this method correspond to the Java class `org.opencv.core.Mat` which has a long attribute named `nativeObj`. So this java class is managing a pointer and it is always passed to the underlying C++ implementation.

On the Java `Mat` object, you have to call the `release` method, which in turn call the JNI function `Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_release`.

The `finalize` method also call `n_delete` which free the memory.

You can see the Java code [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/core+Mat.java).

Comment: I know there is no memory management done here, I was asking where and how it is done.

Comment: I'm on it, two minutes.

Comment: C++ allocated memory via `new` will stay in memory until the corresponding `delete` call.  With jni, I would assume that the Java `dispose` or `finalize` would in turn invoke a native method, passing the jlong variable to be deleted.

Comment: Ok, when I call `Mat()` from java it simply runs `nativeObj = n_Mat();` which will make a jni call and run `JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__
  (JNIEnv*, jclass)
{
    LOGD("Mat::n_1Mat__()");
    return (jlong) new cv::Mat();
}`. But where does release method called from?

Comment: In java it is named as `n_Mat` but in cpp it is named as `n_1Mat__`. Is there another java file between core+Mat.Java and Mat.cpp?

Comment: Actually it's done in `n_delete`. For the in-fixed 1, I don't know where does it come from but according to the comments it refers to the right method.

Comment: Ok, since I'm not familiar with java too much, can you tell me when does finalize run?

Comment: When the object is garbage collected, the finalize method is called to free resources. This is an automated process

Answer (score 4):

Well, I couldn't find the answer but I did a little trick. I defined a member variable as;

```
cv::Mat* mat = nullptr;
```

And when I need to allocate memory for a new `Mat` object first I run the following code and then do the memory allocation.

```
if(mat != nullptr) // this is satisfied if memory is already allocated and not deleted
{
    delete mat;
    mat = nullptr;
}
mat = new cv::Mat(rows, cols, type);
return (jlong)mat;
```

But I'm still loking forward to learn, how does OpenCV overcomes this problem.